# Transfer problems between exchange and wallet

Tags: exchange, wallet, transfer

Using x64 14.1, gave exchange my primary address to send (my first) xmr to my wallet.  Tutorials say that the transfer is seamles but got msg from exchange-"This is a friendly reminder that your request #xxxxxxx is pending. Usually, this means that we are waiting on a response from you in order to solve the request."  I don't see any option in 14.1 to send any kind of response.

Comment: No kind of 'response' is needed in order to properly withdraw to the GUI wallet. When did you initiate this withdrawal request? Perhaps it is simply a matter of time and thus patience is required.

Comment: Indeed, if there is some issue at play, it is that the exchange needs you to do something, like approve the withdrawal. There's nothing to be done in your wallet.